# Django Multipart Upload with Ajax AWS S3 | How to get presigned URL?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, amazon-s3

Brother, i cant get it... so i have this:

> s3fileuploader.py

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig

from .progresshandler import ProgressHandler
from lumen import settings


class S3Uploader(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.s3 = boto3.client('s3',
                               aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                               aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
                               )
        self.config = TransferConfig(
            multipart_threshold=1024 * 100,
            max_concurrency=1,
            multipart_chunksize=1024 * 100,
            use_threads=False
        )
        self.folder_name = 'simple_file_upload'
        self.progress_handler = None

    def upload(self, file_obj, filename, file_type, file_size):
        self.progress_handler = ProgressHandler(self.folder_name, filename, file_size)
      
        self.s3.upload_fileobj(file_obj,
                               settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
                            #    settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
                               f'{self.folder_name}/{filename}',
                               ExtraArgs={'ContentType': file_type},
                               Config=self.config,
                               Callback=self.progress_handler)

    def get_upload_status(self):
        if self.progress_handler:
            return self.progress_handler.get_upload_status()
        return None


class S3ParallelMultipartUploader(S3Uploader):

    def __init__(self):
        super(S3ParallelMultipartUploader, self).__init__()

     
        self.config = TransferConfig(
            multipart_threshold=1024 * 100,
            max_concurrency=10,
            multipart_chunksize=1024 * 100,
            use_threads=True
        )

        self.folder_name = 'multipart_upload'
```

> progresshandler.py

```
    import threading
from time import perf_counter

from django.core.cache import cache


class ProgressHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, cache_key_prefix, filename, size):
        self._filename = filename
        self._size = size
        self.perf_counter_start = perf_counter()

        self.cache_key = f'{cache_key_prefix}_{self._filename}'

        cache.set(self.cache_key, {
            'uploaded_size': 0,
            'progress_perc': 0,
            'time_taken_s': 0
        })

        self._lock = threading.Lock()

    def __call__(self, bytes_amount):
        with self._lock:
            upload_status = cache.get(self.cache_key)
            upload_status['uploaded_size'] += bytes_amount
            upload_status['progress_perc'] = int((upload_status['uploaded_size'] / self._size) * 100)
            upload_status['time_taken_s'] = perf_counter() - self.perf_counter_start
            cache.set(self.cache_key, upload_status)

    def get_upload_status(self):
        upload_status = cache.get(self.cache_key)
        if upload_status:
            return {'progress_perc': upload_status['progress_perc'],
                    'time_taken_s': round(upload_status['time_taken_s'], 2)}

        return {'progress_perc': 0, 'time_taken_s': 0}
```

> views.py

```
    s3uploader = S3ParallelMultipartUploader()


def create_post_aws(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES["file"]
        title = request.POST['title']
        s3uploader.upload(file.file, file.name, file.content_type, file.size)
        s3_con = boto3.client('s3')
        url=s3_con.generate_presigned_url('put_object',
                                  Params={'Bucket': 'bucket',
                                          'Key':file.name,
                                          'ContentType': file.content_type
                                  },
                                  ExpiresIn=600)
        FileFolder = Post()
        FileFolder.title = title
        FileFolder.video = url
        FileFolder.save()

    return render(request, 'main/create_post.html')
```

After allthat it gives me

> DataError at /create-post
> value too long for type character varying(100)

oh and the template:

```
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="margin: 100px auto; display: block;">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="post-form" id="post-form" method="POST" style="text-align: center;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        <p>Title*</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-text-custom" name="title" required id="id_title" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
        <label>Select file to upload*</label>
        <input type="file"  required name="file" accept=".mp4" class="form-control" id="id_video" placeholder="Select file">
    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="file-upload-button" class="btn btn-success">     
        <br /><br />
        <div id="upload-status">
          <h6>Upload Progress: <span id="progress"></span>%</h6>
          <h6>
            Total Time Taken (s): <span id="time-taken">Calculating ....</span>
          </h6>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="uploaded_files"></div>
</div>

<br> 

<script
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  let fileName;
  let updateProgressInterval;
  $("#upload-status").hide();
  
  $("#file-upload-button").click(function (event) {
    // preparing data for file upload POST request

    uploadFile();

    fileName = $("#id_video").prop("files")[0].name;

    $("#upload-status").show();

    // sending GET request after every 0.3 seconds to get file upload progress
    updateProgressInterval = setInterval(updateProgress, 300);
  });

  function uploadFile() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var title = $('#id_title').val()
    formData.append("file", $("#id_video").prop("files")[0]);
    formData.append('title', title)
    formData.append(
      "csrfmiddlewaretoken",
      $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
    );

    $.ajax({
      url: "/create-post",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      },
    });
  }

  function updateProgress() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/create-post/progress?filename=" + fileName,
      async: true,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (response) {
        $("#progress").text(response.progress_perc);
        $("#time-taken").text(response.time_taken_s);

        if (response.progress_perc == 100) {
          // stop sending file upload progress request
          clearInterval(updateProgressInterval);
        }
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Request for file upload status failed: " + xhr.responseText);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error.message);
      },
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Ive search all the web for some answers but i cant find anything, if you are wondering why the method to upload is so complicated is because i want to bypass the Cloudflare upload limit of 100M, so i want to upload in chunks, but i cant get the video url i dont know how to get it, and i dont wanna make them public. BTW i followed [this tutorial](https://muneebshahid.com/improvement-with-s3-multipart-parallel-upload/) I really dont have experience with AWS

PLEASE SOMEONE GUIDE ME IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION